# Смена атрибута title в Яндекс.Поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сменить атрибут title для кнопки ВКонтакте в сервисе Яндекс.Поделиться? Нужно, чтобы при наведении на кнопку во всплывающей подсказке было название на английском, а не на русском.

Что title, который станет заголовком поста передаётся через мета-теги и js код в курсе, нужно поменять именно текст всплывающей подсказки. Разумеется, я могу изменить его через js, но должна же быть такая функция среди исходного функционала блока.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Для перевода используйте параметр темы `lang` при инициализации кнопок:

```
var share = Ya.share2('my-share', {
    theme: {
        lang: 'en'
    }
});
```

Либо через data-атрибут блока:

```
<div class="ya-share2" data-lang="en"></div>
```

Подробнее здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/#theme

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример для конфигурации через data-атрибуты.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев, добавил.